# React conflict when using Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

When attempting to use the AppBar in version 0.16.6 of Material UI, I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.
```

which looks like a react conflict error.

My code is as follows:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import {deepOrange500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    accent1Color: deepOrange500,
  },
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <AppBar/>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Has anyone encountered this, or does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: delete node modules folder and do npm install, if it is a problem of lib conflicts, it will get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In the `index.js` file you will need this before the `ReactDOM.render` call:

```
// Needed for onTouchTap event handling
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

See if that clears up the issue. If not, then try deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.